# Parsing dates using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to read a column with date and time from csv file and wanted to plot the frequencies of datas per day.
I don't actually know how to read them though.

[image: The kind of datas I'm trying to work with]

Comment: Ensure you're using `parse_dates=True` when reading your CSV file. Pandas will do the work for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to define your initial column as datetime first.

```
df['created'] =  pd.to_datetime(df['created'])
```